# WP7 Audio/video files chooser

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am working on an application in witch I need to record/take and choose photos, video and audio files.
I manage to take/select photos, record audios and videos.

But I can't find a way to choose video and audio files.

For the photo selection I used PhotoChooserTask.

I searched the Launchers and Choosers documentation, but found nothing.

Is there such thing, or I need to implement my own?

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no way to select existing video and sound media content through default choosers. You can use [MediaLibrary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.media.medialibrary.aspx) that will give you access to metadata related to existing songs and pictures, but that's about it. You cannot currently access videos stored on the phone.

Also, you cannot access the song streams - those are only read by the OS, so that the users won't be able to copy them through third-party applications.

Comment: Argh, this sucks. +1 for clarifying the limitation. Confirmation here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pl/windowsphone7series/thread/5fe984de-7b0b-44ae-9f08-33ea18dee6a2

Comment: Any word on windows phone 8 SDK allowing video choosing from local device?

Comment: There are no explicit file pickers, but you can associate your application with a specific file type.

Comment: @Den: I must say, but not happy with that :), you cannot register the app for common file types like .mp4 .mpeg. They are "reserved". Not happy because I was hoping to do that in my app.