# Video API in windows phone

Tags: video, windows-phone, media

I've been working on some media player app for Windows Phone 7.5, and I'm yet to figure out how to access the video collection in the phone's internal storage.

Could you please point me in the right direction?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to select existing video and sound media content through default choosers. You can use [MediaLibrary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.media.medialibrary.aspx) that will give you access to metadata related to existing songs and pictures, but that's about it. You cannot currently access videos stored on the phone.

Also, you cannot access the song streams - those are only read by the OS, so that the users won't be able to copy them through third-party applications.

Per [Den Delimarsky](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6812156/wp7-audio-video-files-chooser).