# Share videos camera roll wp 8

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I tired to googling that how share videos form camera roll in windows phone 8 like in **Nokia video upload and facebook** app. I used to try this 
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff967563(v=vs.105).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff967563%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Only share picture but I want to share only videos for my app e.g. when my app show in list when share a video by camera roll of windows phone in sharing

Answer (score 1):

To quote the link you included in your question:

> Note that this extensibility is only available when the photo is a JPG
>   file.

And from my experience, I can confirm that it is not possible to register your app as a share target for a video file.

In other words, if a user tries to share a video from the camera roll or another app, there is no way to make your app appear as one of the options in that list.

Comment: But in f.b app share a video from the camera roll. How they could it?

Comment: That's because Facebook on Windows Phone 8 is very deeply integrated into the system. You can share videos on Facebook on WP8 even if you don't have the Facebook app installed.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using the `share media task` function?

Check this article out from the msdn : 
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207027(v=vs.105).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207027%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [MediaLibrary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.media.medialibrary.aspx) and there is already an answer for your question in this [link.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6812156/wp7-audio-video-files-chooser) As said, there is no way to select existing sound media and video files through default choosers. Thank you.

Comment: library.Songs get empty all time even videos are placed in camera roll?